# Override entityManager factories mapping at conditionally at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a multi tenant/DB application implemented using an `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. Some of the DBs have a slightly different schema and missing some columns in some tables (this is static and known for each DB). Instead of duplicating all repositories and entities for each DB schema I would like to just mark missing columns as transient if the DB does not have the columns (but still save all information if the columns are available).

I was able to override the annotation based mappings in the entity manager factory using an XML based mapping file which I could create for all possible schemas. My idea is to create an entity manager factory for each tenant with the appropriate XML mapping override. Ideally on the first request of a tenant it will instantiate the entity manager factory and then check what mappings override to apply. Pseudo code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
class JPAconfig {

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource myAbstractRoutingDataSource, TenantService tenantService) {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(myAbstractRoutingDataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan("myPackagesToScan");
    final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
    String schemaVer = env.getProperty("db.schema.version");

    // At runtime based on the tenant, override annotation based mappings
    em.setMappingResources(tenantService.getMappingsForTenant());
    
    return em;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` is a factory bean and only seems to allow singleton or prototype scope. It would also be okay to define all possible `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` beans at compile time and somehow select the correct factory based on the tenant at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reload the Application context after change your hibernate properties/config:

```
ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().refresh();
```

Reference: [Spring Hibernate: reload entity mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321050/spring-hibernate-reload-entity-mappings)